# How to use custom express middleware within Nuxt.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nuxt.js, middleware

I am building an app using Nuxt.js. One of the things that drew me to Nuxt specifically, was it's implementation of serverMiddleware.

The app is a cookbook so I can automate meal planning at my house :)

I have the Nuxt app set up with the following middleware

nuxt.config.js

```
serverMiddleware: [{ path: '/api', handler: '~server/main.ts' }],
```

main.ts

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import express, {
    Request,
    Response,
    NextFunction
} from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import routesv1 from './api/endpoints/v1/routes';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

const server = express();

const dbUri: string = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.mongoUser}:${process.env.mongoPassword}@dev.ivzgx.mongodb.net/dev`;

mongoose.connect(dbUri, { ssl: true, sslValidate: false})
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`[${dayjs()}] Connected to MongoDB`);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.warn(error);
    });
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
server.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.info(`[${req.method}] ${req.url} ${res.statusCode}`);
    next();
    });

server.use(express.json());
server.use('/v1', routesv1);

export default server
```

When I run `nom run dev` I see that mongoose has connected, and the server runs properly.

Additionally, I have set up a test route

server/api/endpoints/v1/routes.ts

```
import express, {Request, Response, Express} from 'express';
import validateResource from '../../middleware/validateResource';
import { createRecipeSchema } from '../../schema/recipe.schema';
import { createRecipeHandler } from '../../controller/recipe.controller'

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('test endpoint');
})

router.post('/recipe', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log("router hit; passing to validation middleware")
    validateResource(createRecipeSchema),
    createRecipeHandler
})

export default router
```

Now this is where I am lost...

I am able to hit the test route without any issues; I receive the 200 status, and I receive the 'test endpoint' message.

When I attempt to post data to the recipe endpoint, the console prints that the request was received at the route and is being passed to the following middleware

server/api/middleware/validateResource.ts

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { AnyZodObject } from "zod";

const validate = 
    (schema: AnyZodObject) => 
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        try {
            console.log('attempting to parse schema')

            schema.parse({
                body: req.body,
                query: req.query,
                params: req.params
            });
            next();
        } catch (e: any) {
            return res.status(400).send(e.errors);
        }
    };

export default validate;
```

but the request just hangs and is never passed to the custom middleware...

Is the middleware improperly configured? Does Nuxt not like using additional middleware with express? Please help

Comment: 1) you have `validateResource` instead of `validate` (not sure if that's a Next.js thing), 2) do you call `response.send` in `createRecipeHandler`. Also, you use the term `Next js`, but you tagged the question as `nuxt.js`

Comment: for example, I am sending the following data to the api/v1/recipe endpoint
```
{
    "title": "salad",
    "description": "a quick and easy light dinner or side",
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "name": "grass",
            "description": "fresh from the lawn",
            "type": "vegetable",
            "cost": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "dirt",
            "description": "fresh from the ground",
            "type": "nasty",
            "cost": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use Postman?

Comment: @ps2goat -- thanks for your response. 1) export is defined as the default, so the name validateResource does not have an effect. 2) yes, the next layer of the middleware IS calling res.send as I have run into that issue before. 3) I have updated to only use `Nuxt.js`

Comment: @kissu -- No; I am using postman and the request simply hangs forever

Comment: There's a bare `createRecipeHandler` in `routes.ts` (with a trailing comma on the preceding line), which doesn't look right. Shouldn't you be calling this function?

Comment: @Oblosys -- good eye. Yes, this is expected. Express middleware always receives request, response, and next function by default so passing the parameters is not required.

Comment: @Oblosys -- additionally, I can confirm this works as described above because I have created this exact api using express (outside of Nuxt). This is why I suspect my nuxt configuration may be incorrect..

Comment: if anyone is curious to see this in action, I have a public repo here https://github.com/austin4399/express-api which this Nuxt API is based on

Comment: The difference is that in your repo, the bare function is a parameter to `post`, which makes sense, but in the code above it's in a code block (between braces), which means it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Oblosys -- you are 100% right!! thank you this has been driving me crazy I knew it had to be something minor. I will update the question with the fix shortly